# Prevent VS Code Sidebar from opening automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I prevent Visual Studio Code Sidebar from opening automatically? (see screenshot below)

[image: Image of my Visual Studio Code showcasing side panel being open]

I tried closing it but it will pop up again in new windows.
This wasn't happening before VS Code introduced ports forwarding feature (1.8 version) if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so running "Views: Move secondary side bar views to panel" command does the trick.